# How to specify table name of hasOne property in Grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I use `hasOne` for one-to-one relation in Grails:

```
class MyParent {
    static hasOne = [child: MyChild]
}

class MyChild {
    static belongsTo = [parent: MyParent]
    static mapping = {
        table: 'MyChild'
    }
}
```

I have table in the DB named "MyChild" and thus I get the next error:

```
Invalid object name 'my_child'
```

How can I specify relation's table name in `Parent` class to be "MyChild" and not "my_child"?

Comment: Try it without ':'. static mapping = { table "mychild"} or use name label static mapping = { table name:"mychild" }

Comment: Thanks, Alidad, this was exactly the issue! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it without ':'.

```
static mapping = { table "mychild"}
```

or use name label

```
static mapping = { table name:"mychild" }
```

Hope this helps